# is it possible to emulate the Kinect (useful for debugging code)?

Tags: kinect

I'm developing a Kinect program using the official SDK version 1.5. I was wondering whether it is possible to talk to an emulated kinect device? That would allow for faster coding and debugging, since I don't have to plugin the device but could replay some data.

Is that possible? if so, how do I get started?

Comment: I used to do this using [OpenNI](http://openni.org/) (there were even a few recorded footage in the website). As far as I remember `Microsoft Kinect SDK` didn't have something similar although it has been quite some time since I last used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've only used the offical Kinect SDK for a few days, but recommend having a look at Kinect Studio. There's a good article on [working with Kinect Studio on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj650892.aspx) to get started.